# RaiseEvent works, the same in C# - does not

Tags: c#, vb.net, events

I have a problem which I can't fix. It throws an exception only in C# code, in VB doesn't.
The problem is just in events (oh, yes, it's classic - how it seemed to me by the number of very similar (or so) questions). BUT: I didn`t find an answer.

So, RaiseEvent works, calling the same event from C# - throws an exception.
This event is declared in interface in the same compiled external dll. There's three similar events declared in common library, and there's all the same.

So, part of code in *my common/shared interface library* (I cut the most of code but the event declarations):

```
Public Interface ISolution
    Event ErrorExecuting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal iErrorCode As Integer)
    Event ExecutionFinished(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal Cancelled As Boolean)
    Event ExecutionStarted(ByVal sender As Object)
```

......

IExport is derived from ISolution
And written Class-lib implements IExport (IExport implement ISolution events).
That`s plugin system. I wrote earlier: there're a lot of interfaces implemet ISolution.

**VB.NET code works fine**

*Declaration (implementation):*

```
Public Event ExecutionStarted(ByVal sender As Object) Implements VmS.ISolution.ExecutionStarted
```

*Calling:*

```
RaiseEvent ExecutionStarted(Me)
```

---

**C# throws 'Object referense not set to an instance of an object'**

*Declaration and implementation:*

```
public event VmS.ISolution.ExecutionStartedEventHandler ExecutionStarted;
```

*Calling:*

```
ExecutionStarted(this);
```

There's no event-related code in any of projects, so I omitted remaining one.

I know that mistake is in invoking (from C#) that event.

I`m 10 years in VB5/6, 1 year in VB.NET, and 2 months in C#((
Please help) THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, you need to check that the event is not null before raising it. If no one has registered to it, it is null.

You can either do

```cs
if (ExecutionStarted != null)
{
    ExecutionStarted(this);
}
```

or, shorter

```
ExecutionStarted?.Invoke(this);
```

Comment: Exception disappeared)). The 2nd option helped. Thanks! Shorter one - didn`t (vs 2010).

Comment: Yea, the variant with the ? requires .NET 4.5 or newer. You should upgrade your compiler :-)

Comment: Not .NET 4.5 per se, but C#6. Incidentally, VB code compiles down to the first version.

Comment: @Andy-Kiev If this might be used in a multithreaded context, note the potential race condition in the first way of invoking the event handler (`ExecutionStarted` could theoretically become `null` between when you check and when you try to invoke).  The thread-safe way to do it is to assign to a temp variable, then check for null and invoke on the temp variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need create a function that call to this handler event, I explain me

if you have a code:

```
public event type_handler name_event(type_eventargs e);
```

you need create a function that call to name_event

```
private void on_name_event(type_eventargs e){
   type_handler handler = name_event;
   if(handler != null)
   {
     handler?.invoke(e);
   }
}
```

for finalize use this

```
on_name_event(e);
```

you use this in any function for active this event

for example:

```
public class PersonEntity
{
    event CreateHandler CreatePersonaEventHandler(CreateEventArgs e);

    private onCreatePersonEventHandler(CreateEventArgs e){
        CreateHandler handler = CreatePersonaEventHandler;
        if(handler != null){
            handler?.invoke(e);
        }
    }

    public CreateUser(PersonEntity person){
        CreateEventArgs dataEvent = new CreateEventArgs();
        /*
         your logic for create person
         and
         next to
        */
    
        onCreatePersonEventHandler(dataEvent);//this line execute the event.
    }
}
```